# Swift execute a simple test and pass the result inside a parameter of a function

Tags: swift, function, if-statement, closures, conditional-statements

I have found the below solution to execute a simple 'if ... then ... else' inside a parameter of a function. It is working but I'm quite sure that there is cleaner way to do that in Swift.

I was wondering if the use of closure could be a solution here, but the syntax and the logic of closure are not obvious to me yet. Before learning this part of the language, could someone tell me if it will indeed allow me to have a cleaner way of implementing this simple need ?

```
var tTexteSplitted: Array<String> = ["A", "B", "C"]

for (Index, Texte) in tTexteSplitted.enumerate()
{
    SomeFunction(Texte, TestValue((Index == 0), ReturnTrue: "SomeString", ReturnFalse: "AnotherString"))
}

func TestValue(Test: Bool, ReturnTrue: String, ReturnFalse: String) -> String
{
    if Test { return ReturnTrue } else { return ReturnFalse }
}

func SomeFunction(Param1: String, Param2: String)
{
    // Do something with Param1 and Param2
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear that a closure is needed here:

```
var tTexteSplitted: Array<String> = ["A", "B", "C"]

for (Index, Texte) in tTexteSplitted.enumerate()
{
    SomeFunction(Texte, Index == 0 ? "SomeString" : "AnotherString")
}

func SomeFunction(Param1: String, Param2: String)
{
    // Do something with Param1 and Param2
}
```

Comment: Well...You were the fastest...Gold medal !

Answer (score 1):

The [ternary conditional operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID71) `?:` is the way to go. Use it as follows:

```
var tTexteSplitted = ["A", "B", "C"]

for (Index, Texte) in tTexteSplitted.enumerate()
{
    SomeFunction(Texte, Index == 0 ? "SomeString" : "AnotherString")
}

func SomeFunction(Param1: String, Param2: String)
{
    // Do something with Param1 and Param2
}
```

Comment: Thanks...Silver Medal ;-)